# How to create a letter in the table using its cells?

Tags: php, html

I have two forms...
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Char Display</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="seven.php">
        ROWS <input type="text" name="rows"> COLUMNS <input type="text" name="cols"><input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

seven.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['rows'])){

$rows=$_POST['rows'];
$cols=$_POST['cols'];
echo '<table border="1">';
for($row=1;$row<=$rows;$row++){
    echo '<tr>';

for($col=1;$col<=$cols;$col++){
        echo '<td></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

}
?>
```

The program have two textfields which are the rows and cols. The php script creates a table based on the user's input in the rows and cols.

My problem is that I don't know what/how to do if the program have three textfields which are rows,cols and letters(input one letter from A-Z) and it will create a table of the letter(inputted by the user) based from the number of rows and cols that the user also inputs. Please helpp!!

Answer (score 1):

If there is another input like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Char Display</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="seven.php">
        ROWS <input type="text" name="rows">
        COLUMNS <input type="text" name="cols">
        DATA <input type="text" name="data">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the PHP code read the data field and explode the characters in the data using

`$data_char=explode('',$data);`

Now echo each letter in the exploded `$data_char` array in the `td` tag. 
Make sure the array has value in that index (`$row*$col`) using

`isset($data_char[$row*$col])`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['rows'])){

$rows=$_POST['rows'];
$cols=$_POST['cols'];
$data=$_POST['data'];

$data_char=explode('',$data); // Array of characters in the data

echo '<table border="1">';
for($row=1;$row<=$rows;$row++){
    echo '<tr>';

for($col=1;$col<=$cols;$col++){
        echo '<td>'.isset($data_char[$row*$col])?$data_char[$row*$col]:''.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

}
?>
```

Comment: For what is expload? sorry im fairly new to php and this is my first time encountering that.

Comment: Use [`str_split`](http://php.net/str-split) instead? It is more understandable than [`explode("")`](http://php.net/explode).

Comment: Suppose you have a string that contain `"a.p.p.l.e"` `explode('.',"a.p.p.l.e")` will split the string into  an array using the character provided in this case `'.'`  the array returned here will be `['a','p','p','l','e']`